# Trying to hyperlink a heading for a CV section on Overleaf (Repost)

Tags: overleaf, code, hyperlink

I am working on Overleaf making a resume, and I have hyperlinked my CV heading as follows:

```
\cvsection {\href{https://simply-delicious-food.com/homemade-chicken-nuggets/}{Research Exposure}}
```

I think I discovered the issue. So once I download the pdf the hyper-link for some reason shows up in all caps instead of lowercase, which is why it won't route properly to the website.

However, I don't know why this is happening or how to fix it. I think it might have to do with the fact that `\cvsection` is a heading and therefore all of it is in caps.

Any help appreciated

Comment: sorry but how can anybody help you if you show only one line of code? Make a small but complete example that can be tested.